# assign value to attribute in other thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, static, attributes, lazy-initialization

I want to assign value to `att = 5` in `thread t`. In the `main thread`, I want to check if `att` has been assigned to 5 yet

When I run the `void check()`, the output is always `3`.  Why is this?

```
class Program
{
    static int att = 3;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(() => set(att));
        t.Start();
        check();
    }
    static void set(int para)
    {
        para = 5;
    }
    static void check()
    {
        while (att != 5)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(att);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(att);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are setting `para` to 5, not `att`. `att` never changes so you will never exit that while loop.

Comment: is there any solution to change the value of att in other thread ?

Comment: Change `para = 5;` to `att = 5;`?

Comment: `static int att = 3;` i want to change att = 5

Comment: I know... you aren't reading what im saying. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the value of `para` in your `set()` method won't have any effect on the original value of `att`, unless you specify that the parameter should be passed by reference.

Also, you'll want to call `Join()` on your thread to make sure it doesn't try printing the value to the console before the thread has actually finished modifying it.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(() => set(ref att));
    t.Start();
    t.Join();

    check();
}

static void set(ref int para)
{
    para = 5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are editing the `para` variable rather than the `att` variable so `att` will always equal 3.

Try changing this:

```
static void set(int para)
{
    para = 5;
}
```

To:

```
static void set(int para)
{
    att = 5;
}
```

Comment: what if I have an array of att 
`int[] att = new int[10];`
and I want to change the value of each `att[i]` in different thread `t[0], t[1] . . . t[9]`, and each thread receive method `set`

Comment: @Fish I cant answer that in a comment easily.

Comment: Okey, I've found the solution :) Thanks anyway